# PHP & Docker: script unable to write to /tmp

Tags: php, docker

I have created a Docker image with Nginx & PHP 5 for my project, but i'm getting a runtime error due to lack of permissions on /tmp. Does it have to be a volume or is there a special Dockerfile configuration for this?

```
fopen(/tmp/myerror.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Comment: Could you include the docker run command you used? Is /tmp part of the container or did you mount it on the host with something like -v /tmp:/tmp. If you did not mount the container, then could you say what user (within the container) is running nginx/php and what are the results of "ls -ld /tmp"

Comment: I've got simillar problem and the bash from container level claims that the directory is writable: `drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 05:49 /tmp`

Answer (score 5):

I've had to add RUN chmod 777 -R /tmp && chmod o+t -R /tmp to my Dockerfile in the past

Comment: was that within the container, or are we talking about the host machine which houses all of the containers?

Comment: the Dockerfile creates the container

Comment: this solved it for me, thank you very much.  The sticky bit wasn't set properly in my case as well, nor the umask. Started happening after I blindly ran a [cp] instead of [rsync] (with perms) to move the docker data directory to a new (larger) hard drive. 
Upvoted

Comment: @Barry, It means you need to add this line "RUN chmod 777 -R /tmp && chmod o+t -R /tmp" to your Dockerfile then build your docker image again. Of course, you can run it directly in your container but you have to do that every time you restart your container.

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod 777 (please no ! )
chown -R yourmachinename:yourmachinename /tmp
```